# Understanding Example 0.13 Of Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Example 0.13 of Hatcher's book, he proved that if $(X,A)$ is a CW pair then $X/A$ is homotopically equivalent to mapping cone of the inclusion map $A\to X.$ In the last line he claimed that, $CA$ is a subcomplex  of $X\cup CA.$

I don't understand this part, how $X\cup CA$ is a cw complex and why is $CA$  a subcomplex?

Any help? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, $X$ has a CW structure, as does $A$. Prove that $(A\times I)/(A\times\{1\})$ has a CW structure (Hatcher proves that X/A inherits a cell structure for any CW pair $(X,A)$) and then show that $X\cup CA$ has a CW structure consisting of cells in $X$ and cells in $CA$, with the intersection being cells in $A$.

Comment: @Elliot G can you tell me why the cw complex structure of X/A homeomorphic with X/A?